# Create typebinding in eclipse jdt AST

Tags: java, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm generating source code from a java object with eclipse JDT. While creating a `Type`, for example a `SimpleType` representing a class, how would I add typebindings?

PS: I still have trouble understanding typebinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type bindings are not created nor assigned by clients of JDT. Binding are created by the compiler as a result of parsing and resolving a Java file.

So, if you implement a tool that in step 1 generates a class and in step 2 needs a binding of that class: save the class from step 1, and re-read it using the `ASTParser` after setting `setResolveBindings(true)`.

Otherwise, if you are just creating this one class, don't worry about the binding, it's only the AST that will determine the resulting source file.